# GSS Failed: Invalid name provided error in Mathematica on Raspberry Pi

Tags: sql, networking, raspberry-pi, wolfram-mathematica, ethernet

I have written a program that imports company data and performs statistical analysis, with the primary output being a Shewhart Chart. The goal of this program is to have it work on a Raspberry Pi as that's the cheapest option available. Because of this, I've written the program in Mathematica as that allows a seamless transition to the Raspbian operating system. All operations are done on the Pi, including the data importation, the calculations, and the graphing.

The problem that I've encountered occurs when I attempt to set up a connection to certain databases. These databases are accessed with individual network credentials, so long as the employee is on the permissions list. I have access to these databases, and therefore the program works fine on my Windows PC. When I try to connect to the database using Mathematica on the Pi though, I get the following error:

```
JDBC: I/0 Error: GSS Failed: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
```

I get this error from this code when running it on a Pi, but not when using it on my PC:

```
conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)","SERVERNAME:PORT/DatabaseName"]]
```

What I also find confusing is that I'm connecting my Pi using an ethernet cable directly to the ethernet port, and normal internet capabilities are working. In addition to that, I can connect to databases that have their own username and password instead of the network credentials without any problems, using syntax similar to:

```
conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)","SERVERNAME:PORT/DatabaseName"],
"Username"->"USERNAME","Password"->"PASSWORD"]
```

I've also tried inputting my network credentials in the username and password in a variety of ways on the Pi, but I've had no results so far.

Is there a way that I can associate my network credentials with a Raspberry Pi B+ running the latest edition of Raspbian Jessie connected by Ethernet in order to make this error go away? If not, is there a way to do it by Wifi? We use a WPA2-Enterprise connection and I have not had luck with that either, though I do not believe I've set it up correctly.